# Reset a user's password each time after restart in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: password, startup

I want to create a user in ubuntu and if he change his password, I want to reset his password to something after computer restart. How can I do this in ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Just to be clear, do you need to reset the password to a known default at each reboot? Or to something "random", and only if the user changes it?

Comment: To check if password changed you should compare hash of password with old hash in /etc/shadow

Comment: @MrShunz Reset to a password defined by me and the user knows this password but if he change it, I want to reset it back to the password defined by me(after computer startup). I think it is not necessary to check if he changed it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mr Shunz](https://askubuntu.com/users/4887/mr-shunz)' [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113501/504066) already shows, `chpasswd` can be used to set a user's
password without being prompted for confirmation. Usually, `chpasswd`
deals with cleartext passwords but the `-e` switch tells it to expect
already *encrypted* passwords instead.

Suppose, we want to set the password of user `rembo` to `secret`.

1. If it is not already installed, install `mkpasswd` with

   ```
   sudo apt install whois
   ```
2. Create an encrypted SHA-512 of the password `secret` and put it
    together with the username in a file:

   ```
   echo "rembo:$(mkpasswd -m SHA-512 secret)" > rembo.password
   ```

   The file `rembo.password` will look similar to

   ```
   rembo:$6$S14xGVpG$J0jUOMMF9cd7/ld69bZbDHbw7BJ8nidLdVz.pdSywUX/H.Vlj8/c9KSo.1T3J1Rub8JktYjzwTqSF7bBldikG0
   ```
3. Run `chpasswd` as before but this time with the `-e` switch:

   ```
   sudo chpasswd -e < rembo.password
   ```

This way you do not need to store the cleartext password in a file, but only the encrypted one.

Answer (score 1):

To change a password from a script, you can use the the `chpasswd` program, with this syntax:

```
echo "username:averysecretpassword" | sudo chpasswd
```

You can easily wrap up a script with all the needed user/password combinations and run it at each reboot, either via a `@reboot` cronjob, or on your own `systemd` script, or the good old `/etc/rc.local`.

Please make sure to protect the script as the passwords will be **in cleartext**. Only `root` should be able to read/execute it.